# GitLab CI and Kubernetes - is possible to creating pods from gitlab ci file?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

On our own server cloud we have a problem with gitlab CI and integration tests.

Gitlab have workers, and problem is in one worker = one pod. When project has 12 integrations we need to wait long time to docker-compose turn on all containers. It would be the best, if from the level of gitlab-ci file i could define other pods (integrations) and after build kill them all.

Do you know some possible solutions?

Comment: Maybe is possible to run gitlab ci services as pods?

Comment: Please describe your setup with more details. The mixture of docker-compose and Kubernetes sounds odd? It's unclear what the "one worker = one pod" problem refers to.

Comment: We need run as many pods as we have integrations, and after pipeline end - kill them all. Every integration like db or other service must operate in different pod. Running many applications in one pod (even with docker compose) is really inefficient

Comment: Please edit your question rather than answer my comment. Running more than one container per pod is an anti-pattern (which can be applied if you have reason to do so).